# AWS MySQL Connection timeout

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I setup a mysql DB instance with elasticbeanstalk. but Im unable to connect to the DB via mySQL commandline tool or the workbench.

troubleshooting steps so far:

1. ping - No response time out.
2. WorkBench - Timeout
3. Commandline - Timeout

   [image]

I figured this could be a firewall issue so I changed the security groups assigned to the DB to all all traffic.

[image]

Still unable to connect. Need some advice with other troubleshooting steps or solutions for how I can connect to the DB instance.

[image]

Comment: Is your rds in public subnet? Have you enabled public IP for the rds?

Comment: public accessibility is set to No, I guess I'll change that.

Comment: @Marcin It works now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. I just added an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, the problem was the RDS had `Public IP` disabled. Thus, the solution was to enable it.